# Why does cycle increment and not print out just the number of cycles?

Tags: c, input, output, user-input, increment

Please I have my code below. I am trying to get 8, 3, 1, 8, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1. For the cycles in the output of my code, when the user inputs 45 23 6 12 0 0 0 0 0 0. But for some reason it adds up the next number subtracted by 1. So I get 8, 10, 10, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17. I have tried to fix this but nothing I do seems to help. Can someone please help me point out the reason why this is happening?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int sum_divisors(int); //Function Prototype

/*Just wanted to do an example to show you don't need
 *function prototypes if you write the function itself
 *before main.
 */
int cycles(int x){
    static int count = 1;
    int j;
    if(x == sum_divisors(x)){
        printf("%d%13d Cycle(s) \n", x, count);
    }else{
        x = sum_divisors(x);
        count++;
        printf("%d, ",x);
        cycles(x);
    }
}

int main(void){ //Start of main
    int count = 0;
    int x, sum;
    int i = 0;
    int nums [9];

    puts("Please enter 10 integers. Fill up the rest with 0s. Please only type in numbers if not you might not get the output you want.");

    while(scanf("%d ", &x) != EOF){
        if(x > 100){
            puts("Wrong input");
            exit(1);
        }else{
            count++;
            nums[i] = x;
            ++i;
        }           

        if(i == 9){
            break;
        }
    }

    for(i=0; i<count; i++){
        sum = sum_divisors(nums[i]);
        printf("%d, ", nums[i]);
        cycles(nums[i]);
    }

    puts("");

    return 0;
} //end of main

int sum_divisors(int n){

    int i;
    int sum = 0;
    int prime_ind = 0;

    if(n <= 1){
        sum = 0;
        return sum;
    }

    for(i=2; i<n; i++){
        if(n%i == 0){
            prime_ind = 1;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(prime_ind == 0){
        sum = 1;
    }else{
        for(i=1; i<((n/2)+1); i++){
            if(n%i == 0){
                sum += i;
            }
        }
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: You access index out of bounds here -`nums[i] = x;` . Take a look at loop breaking condition in `if` block.

Comment: You are invoking undefined behaviour by accessing your `nums` array out of its bounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have reviewed your program. 
Your problem is in the function

```
 int cycles(int x){}
```

so change it to

```
int cycles(int x){
    static int count = 1;
    int j;
    if(x == sum_divisors(x)){
        printf("%d%13d Cycle(s) \n", x, count);
        count=1; // add this line 

    }else{
        x = sum_divisors(x);
        count++;
        printf("%d, ",x);
        cycles(x);
    }
}
```

here static variable is not initialized when new cycle() called.

Comment: Have an upvote for bothering to figure out what the code was intended to do, and finding the fix. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
int cycles(int x){
    static int count = 1;
```

A static variable like that will be initialized to the given value *on the first execution of that line **only**.* After that, it will keep its value across multiple function calls, not only the recursive ones but also "fresh" calls from `main()`. You just *keep* incrementing `count`. It will never be reset to `1`.

I think that is not (exactly) what you wanted. It's hard to say, really, because you did not tell us what your functions are actually *intended* to do -- neither in the question nor, as I would have preferred, in comments. I'm not in a mind of reverse-engineering that information.

I also stopped checking your code at that point, as the `static` is very likely to be the core of your problem. There might be more issues, like the out-of-bounds accesses hinted at by comments.